# jsRender Loading Remote Templates (AJAX Data Issue)

Tags: jquery, jsrender

I'm trying to upgrade a website to use the jsRender templates (it used to use the jTemplates) and I have been studying jsRender (both Boris' site and the material produced by John Papa) and trying to follow the instructions here: [JSViewsRemoteLoadTemplates](http://www.jsviews.com/#samples/jsr/composition/remote-tmpl)

*Please note as of 11/13/13 this question was edited to reflect a partial solution and clean up the content:*

After a lot of experimentation I was able to get the jsRender template to work with static data but once I change the data to the ajax source the template renders empty. I believe it might be rendering empty because I'm not specifying the correct wording inside the .js template itself but I've tried all sorts of variations and nothing is working yet.

My page is a basic .htm page. I am using jQuery 1.10.2, json.js, and jsrender.min.js in the header. This is my script on the page:

```
<script style='text/javascript'>
$(function () {
    lazyGetTemplate('PopupChildren');
});

function lazyGetTemplate(name) {
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    if ($.templates[name]) {
        deferred.resolve();
    }
    else {
        $.getScript("/_Scripts/" + name + ".js").then(function () {
            if ($.templates[name]) {
                deferred.resolve();
            }
            else {
                alert("Script: \"" + name + ".js\" failed to load.");
                deferred.reject();
            }
        });
    }
}

/* This is my sample static data that jsRender works with */
var staticdata = [
{
    "TypeID": "88", "Value": "ORGANICS"
},
{
    "TypeID": "89", "Value": "SPECIFIED ORGANICS"
}
];

function getMyTemplate(data) {
    $div_Child.html($.templates.PopupChildren.render(data)); 
 //change data to staticdata to test static info, I've also set this to JSON.stringify(data) but the result is still empty
}

/* This is the ajax that calls the external function I'm using for testing */
function selItem(cControl, treeID, treeTrans) {
    var parentID = treeID;

    if ($(cControl).parent().find('ul').length == 0) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "Post",
            url: "Contractor_ws.asmx/web_getChildren",
            async: true,
            dataType: "text",
            data: "{parentID:" + parentID + ", popupType:'" + $('#hid_popupType').val() + "'}",
            contentType: "application/json",
            success: function (data) {
                if (data != null) { //menu item has children
                    $(cControl).after("<div id=\"div_Child\"></div>");
                    $div_Child = $(cControl).parent().find('#div_Child');
                    $div_Child.hide();
                    getMyTemplate(data); 
                    $div_Child.show('slow');
                }
            },
            error: function (xhr) {
                alert(xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
    }
}

</script>
```

PopupChildren Script (the template):

```
$.templates("PopupChildren", "<ul>{{for}}<li><a onclick='selItem(this,'{{:TypeID}}','{{:Value}}');'>{{:Value}}</a></li>{{/for}}</ul>");
```

Sample ajax data:

data: "{"d":[{"__type":"BLS","TreeCode":"0130","TreeType":"OBJ","ParentID":88,"Children":[],"TypeID":89,"Value":"INORGANIC ACIDS, UNSPECIFIED","Trans":"INORGANIC ACIDS, UNSPECIFIED","Active_Flag":false},{"__type":"BLS","TreeCode":"0131","TreeType":"OBJ","ParentID":88,"Children":[],"TypeID":90,"Value":"CHLORINE-CONTAINING OXYACIDS","Trans":"CHLORINE-CONTAINING OXYACIDS","Active_Flag":false}]}"

Answer (score 0):

First - did you look at the "Full Code" tab on the [JSViewsRemoteLoadTemplates](http://www.jsviews.com/#samples/jsr/composition/remote-tmpl) page? You can run that HTML page as a starting point for testing and modifying the sample

`$.when()` is used for combining promises. In your example above there is only one - so you can write (without using `$.when`):

```
function getMyTemplate() {
    lazyGetTemplate("PopupChildren")
        .done(function () {
            var html = $.templates.PopupChildren.render(data);
            $div_Child.html(html);
         });
}
```

But for your template to work, the current syntax is `{{if ...}} {{/if}}` and similarly for `{[for ...}}`.

`{{#if ...}} {{#/if}}` is incorrect. (Also you have an extra `+`: `'{{#/if}}' + );`)

And in your simplified template, you should be writing `{{for Children}}` - I assume. `{{for}}` on its own won't do anything...

Comment: Hi, Boris, I made some progress and have posted a major revision to my question up above so some of my earlier questions are no longer applicable. Do you have any thoughts on why the ajax is not being read?

Comment: You still have {{for}} with no parameter - isn't that supposed to iterate over the Children?

Comment: Just wanted to say thanks for you're patience and helping me resolve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to the problem I was having and it was combination of how I was calling the template and the parameters set in ajax. Here is the solution that worked for me:

```
$(function () { /* js ready function */
    lazyGetTemplate('PopupChildren');
});

/* this is the function that loads the template from the script */
function lazyGetTemplate(name) {
   var deferred = $.Deferred();
   if ($.templates[name]) {
       deferred.resolve();
   }
   else {
    $.getScript("/_Scripts/" + name + ".js").then(function () {
        if ($.templates[name]) {
            deferred.resolve();
        }
        else {
            alert("Script: \"" + name + ".js\" failed to load.");
            deferred.reject();
        }
    });
   }
 }

/* this is the ajax calling my additional items for display */
function selItem(cControl, treeID, treeTrans) {
var parentID = treeID;

if ($(cControl).parent().find('ul').length == 0) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "Post",
        url: "Contractor_ws.asmx/web_getChildren",
        async: true, 
        dataType: "JSON",
        data: "{parentID:" + parentID + ", popupType:'" + $('#hid_popupType').val() + "'}",
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function (data) {
            if (data != null) { //menu item has children
                $(cControl).after("<div id=\"div_Child\"></div>");
                $div_Child = $(cControl).parent().find('#div_Child');
                $div_Child.hide();
                var myData = data.d;
                $div_Child.html($.templates.PopupChildren.render(myData));
                $div_Child.show('slow');
            }
        },
        error: function (xhr) {
            alert(xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
  }
}

/* this is the content of the actual script that gets called from the lazyGetTemplate() */
$.templates("PopupChildren", "<ul>{{for}}<li><a onclick=\"selItem(this,\'{{:TypeID}}\',\'{{:Value}}\');\">{{:Value}}</a>{{/for}}</ul>");
```

Some specific notes about what I learned while implementing this particular jQuery for js/jsRender newbies. I had to make sure the template was loading onto the page before it was called. I also had to reference 'data.d' when I passed the data to the template. Calling data was not sufficient. I also wasted some precious time when I got confused by the ajax data and thought that the items I was trying to display were inside an array called Children, which I discovered was not the case. And the final two pieces that made this work were I had to set async to true and I had to set dataType to "JSON". Specifically about the dataType, there is another post that mentions setting it 'text' to make it work, and with my problem that didn't wind up being applicable but its something that might help someone else in the future. And last, specifically about the template script itself, I did not have to list an actual item name with the for statement. I thought based on some examples I had seen that I needed to put {{for data}} or {{for Children}} but, I am assuming, because I passed data.d in the end, just calling the {{for}} was sufficient.

Comment: If you are rendering against myData, which is an array (data.d, right?) then your template will be rendered once for each item in the array, and the {{for}} will do nothing, so you will be rendering <ul><li>...</li></ul><ul><li>...</li></ul>... If you instead render against data, you can write <ul>{{for d}}<li>... which will iterate just the <li>s against the array d.